How to prevent 8007: STATUS_RADIO_ERROR when using Android Nearby Connections?
I have three devices which are trying to communicate using Android's Nearby Connections API. The network is set up using a P2P_Cluster strategy, and each device is performing both advertising and discovery. When the devices have all found each other and established a connection, advertising and discovery are turned off. Each device has Bluetooth, Wifi and location enabled, and they are all within two meters of each other.
I find that this setup sometimes works nicely and the devices establish a stable connection, but often they struggle and produce this 8007: STATUS_RADIO_ERROR when trying to request connection (sometimes 8012: STATUS_ENDPOINT_IO_ERROR as well, but that one is less common).
According to the docs this happens when "There was an error trying to use the phone's Bluetooth/WiFi/NFC capabilities." But the devices are perfectly able to access the internet over Wifi so I don't think there's anything wrong with their Wifi in general.
Is there something wrong with my setup causing the devices to struggle to connect to each other? Or is the Nearby Connections API just randomly unreliable?
Edit: Here are the logs when the STATUS_RADIO_ERROR occurs:
2024-07-11 12:42:20.577  1763-9711  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  EndpointManager send a KEEP_ALIVE frame (seqNum:5) and sleep 5000 for endpoint QO61.
2024-07-11 12:42:23.577  1763-9454  NearbyMediums           com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  MEDIUM_ERROR [SYSTEM][BLUETOOTH][CONNECT][ESTABLISH_CONNECTION_FAILED][UNKNOWN], service-id=com.companyname.appname.pos.debug
2024-07-11 12:42:23.577  1763-9454  NearbyMediums           com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  Extra Sensitive/PII message : BluetoothSocketName : {IjZHTEnwg7QAAAAAAAAADVROMDkxOENSNDA0ODE:com.companyname.appname.pos.debug}, Exception : read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
2024-07-11 12:42:23.579  1763-9663  NearbyMediums           com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  MEDIUM_ERROR [SYSTEM][BLUETOOTH][CONNECT][ESTABLISH_CONNECTION_FAILED][EXECUTION_EXCEPTION], service-id=com.companyname.appname.pos.debug
2024-07-11 12:42:23.581  1763-9663  Nearby                  com.google.android.gms.persistent    W  Failed attempt #3 out of 3 for ConnectToBluetoothDevice [CONTEXT service_id=49 ]
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create client Bluetooth socket to {IjZHTEnwg7QAAAAAAAAADVROMDkxOENSNDA0ODE:com.companyname.appname.pos.debug}.
                                                                                                        at bvvk.call(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):31)
                                                                                                        at eeya.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):20)
                                                                                                        at bvvl.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):84)
                                                                                                        at bvzk.i(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):43)
                                                                                                        at bvzo.o(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):36)
                                                                                                        at bvzo.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):614)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.nearby.mediums.bluetooth.BluetoothClassic.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):112)
                                                                                                        at bsxm.c(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):43)
                                                                                                        at btcq.f(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):76)
                                                                                                        at btbb.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):60)
                                                                                                        at bszi.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):648)
                                                                                                        at bsmg.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):20)
                                                                                                        at amhz.c(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):50)
                                                                                                        at amhz.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):76)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                        at amnn.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):8)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2024-07-11 12:42:23.613  1763-9663  NearbyMediums           com.google.android.gms.persistent    W  Failed to create client Bluetooth socket because we failed to register the MediumOperation.
2024-07-11 12:42:23.614  1763-9663  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    W  Failed to connect to endpoint 6GLI over medium BLUETOOTH [CONTEXT service_id=54 ]
                                                                                                    btba: In bluetoothConnectImpl(), failed to connect to Bluetooth device 0C:25:76:31:52:76 for endpoint 6GLI
                                                                                                        at btcq.f(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):178)
                                                                                                        at btbb.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):60)
                                                                                                        at bszi.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):648)
                                                                                                        at bsmg.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):20)
                                                                                                        at amhz.c(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):50)
                                                                                                        at amhz.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):76)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                        at amnn.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):8)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2024-07-11 12:42:23.615  1763-9663  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    W  requestConnection() for client 167916638 failed to initialize the connection with endpoint 6GLI [CONTEXT service_id=54 ]
                                                                                                    btba: Failed to connect to endpoint 6GLI
                                                                                                        at btbb.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):128)
                                                                                                        at bszi.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):648)
                                                                                                        at bsmg.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):20)
                                                                                                        at amhz.c(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):50)
                                                                                                        at amhz.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):76)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                        at amnn.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):8)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2024-07-11 12:42:23.616  1763-9663  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  PcpManager got CONNECTION_RESPONSE OfflineFrame from endpoint QO61 (with status 0, response ACCEPT).
2024-07-11 12:42:23.616  1763-9663  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  Endpoint QO61 has accepted the connection
2024-07-11 12:42:23.616  1763-9663  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  Endpoint QO61 has SafeToDisconnectVersion = 4
2024-07-11 12:42:23.617  1763-9663  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  Waiting for the client to decide whether or not to accept the connection to endpoint QO61
2024-07-11 12:42:23.617  1763-9663  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  Client 167916638 has accepted the connection with endpoint QO61
2024-07-11 12:42:23.618  1763-9710  NearbyConnections       com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  EndpointManager received a KEEP_ALIVE frame (seqNum:0) and reply a KEEP_ALIVE frame with ack from endpoint QO61 on channel BLUETOOTH.
2024-07-11 12:42:23.618  1763-9621  Nearby                  com.google.android.gms.persistent    W  Method finished running after 33124 millis. [CONTEXT service_id=49 ]
                                                                                                    bsmd: bsmd
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
                                                                                                        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:421)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
                                                                                                        at bsni.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):1)
                                                                                                        at bsqw.call(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):121)
                                                                                                        at bsrc.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):5)
                                                                                                        at bsmg.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):20)
                                                                                                        at amhz.c(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):50)
                                                                                                        at amhz.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):97)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                                        at amnn.run(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):8)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                                    Caused by: bsmd
                                                                                                        at bsmi.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):3)
                                                                                                        at bsmj.a(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):3)
                                                                                                        at bsnl.execute(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):5)
                                                                                                        at bsru.c(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):8)
                                                                                                        at bsqt.p(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):639)
                                                                                                        at bvpi.hd(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):489)
                                                                                                        at nni.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):96)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                                                                                                        at azmj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@241615009@24.16.15 (040300-627785391):147)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
2024-07-11 12:42:23.621  7389-7389  NCTAG                   com.companyname.appname.pos.debug  I  req connection failure 6GLI
                                                                                                    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8007: STATUS_RADIO_ERROR
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzig.setFailedResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby@@19.0.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzgw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby@@19.0.0:4)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzkj.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby@@19.0.0:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby@@19.0.0:3)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)


For STATUS_RADIO_ERROR, if it is a session broadcaster then stop and restart the advertising process. If it is a session subscriber then stop and restart the discovery process which will ideally help us to rejoin to the same session.
